# bootstrap submenu width 100

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to open sub menu (ul) width 100% it as. but it always opens up in the dropdown width.

```
<li class="nav-item  drop-menu"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ürünler & Kataloglar</a> <ul style="position:relative;display:inline-block;width:100%;z-index:888;background-color:white;">
        <li ><a href="#">Rich</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shay</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jose</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jamie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Andrew</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teddie</a></li></ul></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using percentages for setting width, it is always set according to the parent element (the *dropdown* width). To achieve a full screen width you can

- Set the dropdown to a 100% width
- Set the submenu to a pixel width

Comment: <li class="nav-item  drop-menu" style="width:100% ;background-color:white;"> not working.

Comment: You might want to post a bit more code. I guess the first <li> is listed in an <ul> element, right ?

Comment: I added all the code. I want to open the full width of dropdown section.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav mx-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item"> 
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kurumsal</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item  drop-menu" >
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#"  >Ürünler & Kataloglar</a>
        <ul style="position:absolute;display:inline-block;width:100% ;background-color:white;">
        <li ><a href="#">Rich</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shay</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jose</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Simon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jamie</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Andrew</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teddie</a></li>
        </ul>  
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item" > 
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Satış & Servis</a> 


                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ar-Ge</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item drop-menu">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Haberler</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">İletişim</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search header-search"></i></a>

                                <!-- When 767px -->
                                <input type="search" placeholder="Ne Aramıştınız?" class="new-search">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```